# Writing the introduction, I want to know if using phrases like "in my opinion" are stylish or not

Tags: writing

I want to know if using phrases like "personally speaking" or phrases like that contributes to good style. Do good writers use such expressions?  Am I better off simply stating my thesis without using these phrases?

I want to make the reader of my essay think that I am different from other writers. Is this the way to do it or do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Style is not the way to distinguish yourself, especially if you're not sure of what's stylish. If you are different from other writers, make it obvious by giving more and better information more clearly than they do.

Answer (score 1):

The word *thesis* says to me that your writing is of a formal nature, or least it could be. A thesis is best supported by reasoning, by citing reliable authorities, by providing the results of your careful investigations, experiments, and controlled observation, to name just a few bases of support.

To qualify your thesis is perfectly OK. Call it the tolerance factor, the plus or minus factor, or the general rule to which there may be exceptions. There are times when you need to distinguish between what has been proved convincingly and what is either merely opinion or perhaps an educated guess. Readers generally respond favorably to an admission of fallibility. Many theses conclude with comments which temper dogmatism with a little humility. For example,

> "There is still a great deal of research to do regarding **_____________**, but I hope I have at least presented a solid foundation upon which to build the findings and subsequent hypotheses of future research."

Comment: Yes; hedging is nigh-on essential where certainty cannot be assumed, but 'In my opinion' is in the wrong register for a weighty article. In the pub, fine. It's a 'modality pragmatic marker'.

Answer (score 0):

An introduction is where you orient your reader by

- explaining what the thesis is about.
- explaining (and showing that you know) the background knowledge needed.

There may be differences of opinion in the field and this is where you can show that they exist. But it's not the place for you to take sides.

The place for your opinions is the conclusion. The body of your thesis should have shown that you are qualified to have an opinion on the topic, so you can give them here. But they should be respectful,  muted and cautious. You are a newcomer to the field and, who knows, a person assessing your work could hold an opposing position.